# Reuse a S25FL256S SPI 32MB flash module even when it is possibility protected?

Tags: microcontroller, programming, flash, eeprom, reuse

This is my weekend toy, a Spansion/Cypress fl256saif00 (S25FL256S), a 32MB SPI module. This chip is salvaged from a Cisco EPC3928 Docsis 3.0 Modem Router (2012).

---

[image: S25FL256S on breakout board]

---

The (first) challenge was to be able to remove it from the donor PCB without damage it and to solder it on a breakout board, just for practice. This seems to be successful so far, nice result. Pretty good for just a first-timer. Because of this result, I just thinking of reusing it with use of a MCU.

---

I have downloaded the datasheet (it is huge!) and also found a library to create a filesystem on it. However, there are some questions, because this chip is not new and there are several memory protection methods described in the datasheet. I cannot figure out whether it is temporary (active when used inside application) or permanent (forever). For example write protection on some memory areas. I will spend some time on it and want to know for sure, that is not unusable by protection (thus a waste of time), for example impossible to reformat and write data/files to it. It must be fun, no frustration ;-)

---

So my question/doubts (before I start this investigation/journey) are:

- Is it possible when it is protected to unlock the protection by reformat/clear the whole flash memory? Can I reuse it anyway?
- In the datasheet, there are several packages, except mine (see picture above). There is a 16-lead SOIC displayed that match the pins however not the size (width), is this actually the same?

---

*Datasheet references:*

*The datasheets, there are two versions of the same, one branded Spansion and one branded Cypress. I have read that Cypress bought Spansion in 2015, that's the reason there are two brandnames involved. I think I must use the first one, since the IC is labeled with the brand "Spansion" and module is of a device of 2012.*

- [Datasheet PDF: Spansion version](https://openwrt.org/_media/media/datasheets/flash/s25fl128s_256s_00.pdf)
- [Datasheet PDF: Cypress version](http://www.cypress.com/file/177966/download)

Comment: It looks like if the password protection is set, there is no way to erase it or disable it. This means that you wont be able to write any data.

Comment: See comment at your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comment:
If the Password Protection is set, there is no way to remove it or change the password, as detailed on page 63 of the cypress doc

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, read it take some time, skip the whole idea. As far I can understand, the both versions explain later on (with use of many words and differently) that you can protect it, by: 
- boot code (optional)
- permanent setting and cannot be changed. I think Cisco will go for the last one so they use a password (to be able to flip the ppb-flag to 1) to be able to update the firmware. I don't think it is worth to spend hours on this and hopefully suspect they did by boot code.  Besides, it is kinda strange the chip only supports protection on writing.